# SQL: Column called IN is causing error in query

Tags: sql

I'm, trying to run a SQL query that contains a crucial column someone else called "IN":

```
SELECT id, count(v1) as v1, AVG(IN) as code, SUM(v2) as v2
FROM datatable
GROUP BY id, IN
```

It is causing error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.

probably it mistakes it as the `IN` SQL operator. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `IN` is a SQL keyword.  Don't use it for a table or column name.

Comment: I didn't choose that. I need to work on data tables created in the past by other people

Answer (score 2):

you can use `[]` if sql server

```
 SELECT id, count(v1) as v1, AVG([IN]) as code, SUM(v2) as v2
    FROM datatable
    GROUP BY id,[IN]
```

OR if you have mysql then use back tick ``

```
SELECT id, count(v1) as v1, AVG(`IN`) as code, SUM(v2) as v2
        FROM datatable
        GROUP BY id,`IN`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be able to get around this by putting the table name in the front of the column:

```
SELECT id, count(v1) as v1, AVG(datatable.IN) as code, SUM(v2) as v2
FROM datatable
GROUP BY id, IN
```

or you may be also able to put the IN in []